# PHP return price with decimal separator

Tags: php, woocommerce, decimal, separator, price

Could you please help me out how I would be able to customize the output of the below code which was added to WordPress/Woocommerce? I would like to have the return values (regular and sales price) separated with a decimal separator (dot) after the thousands, like for example "1.200".

The code:

```
function sr_change_variable_price($price, $product){
    $html_tag = '<span id="reg_price">%s</span><span id="sale_price">%s</span>';
    if($product->is_type('variable') AND !is_product()){
        $test = $product->get_variation_regular_price('min') . ' Ft' ;
        $min = $product->get_variation_sale_price('min') . ' Ft';
        return(sprintf($html_tag, $test, $min));
    }elseif($product->is_type('variable') AND is_product()){
        return('');
    }else
    {return $price;  // other cases
    }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'sr_change_variable_price', 10, 2);
```

Thank you very much for any help

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: I'm not familiar with Woocommerce but it must certainly have price formatting as builtin feature. How is it done elsewhere?

Comment: wc_price()? https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/useful-functions/#section-3

Comment: Should this be localized? E.g 1.200 for some and 1,200 for others, depending their settings? Or always 1.2000 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) for that.

Example:

```
$price = number_format(1200, 0, '', '.');
echo $price; // outputs 1.200
```

Comment: This is a PHP builtin function that will ignore application internationalisation settings.

Comment: Thank you @mxlhz, based on your answer I was able to modify it!